# Не запускается приложение в эмуляторе

Tags: android, android-studio

```
12-19 15:28:09.009 7019-7019/com.evgeniy.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.evgeniy.myapplication, PID: 7019 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.evgeniy.myapplication/com.evgeniy.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evgeniy.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.evgeniy.myapplication-EGoiViJ5PrUzX-2IJHwhcA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.evgeniy.myapplication-EGoiViJ5PrUzX-2IJHwhcA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evgeniy.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.evgeniy.myapplication-EGoiViJ5PrUzX-2IJHwhcA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.evgeniy.myapplication-EGoiViJ5PrUzX-2IJHwhcA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] 
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Как исправить? Что это за ошибки?

**UPD**.

Манифест

```
<activity android:name=".MyApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" > <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

Код MainActivity:

```
package com.evgeniy.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.evgeniy.myapplication.R;

/**
 * Copyright (c) 2017.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 * <p>
 * Author: Pugachev Evgeniy <epygachovs26@mail.ru>
 * Date:   21.12.17
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static class Item {
        String name;
        int pricee;

        Item(String name, int pricee) {
            this.name = name;
            this.pricee = pricee;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText pricee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pricee);
        final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        final ListView items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.items);
        final ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter();

        items.setAdapter(adapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.add(new Item(name.getText().toString(), Integer.valueOf(pricee.getText().toString())));
            }
        });
    }

    private class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
        ItemsAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            final Item item = getItem(position);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(item.name);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pricee)).setText(String.valueOf(item.pricee));
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

UPD. Приложение запустилось, при нажатии кнопки добавить в список выходит такая ошибка и приложение вылетает.

```
12-20 15:43:45.076 3787-3787/com.evgeniy.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.evgeniy.myapplication, PID: 3787
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.evgeniy.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Попробуйте `InstantRun` настройку в студии отключить

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: Попробуйте ещё `clean` проекта сделать.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё `invalidate cache and restart` в студии сделать.

Comment: Также покажите пакет класса актвити, объявление оной в манифесте и в какой папке/пакете лежит файл класса активити.

Comment: invalidate cache and restart попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не понял что сделать с активити

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Может свяжемся вк, тимвивер? Мне бы исправить ошибку, в 10 часов курсовую сдавать идти с этим приложением) Или я могу вам  отправить это приложение, вы может посмотрите в чем проблема

Comment: Чем больше информации в вопросе - тем выше вероятность получить ответ. Если бы вы добавили манифест в вопрос - ответ был бы у вас ещё вчера)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В теге активити в анифесте должен быть указан класс активити, а не класс приложения. У вас указано так:

```
<activity android:name=".MyApplication"
```

а надо так:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: поменял, все так же, ".MainActivity" красным светится

Comment: @Zhekich, вчера я просил  `Также покажите пакет класса актвити, объявление оной в манифесте и в какой папке/пакете лежит файл класса активити`. Вы показали только манифест. Покажите остальное. И не в комментах, но в вопросе через правку оного.

Comment: "в какой папке/пакете лежит файл класса активити" где это смотреть?

Comment: Пакет это папка. Смотреть можно в студии или файловом менеджере

Comment: вы этот код имели ввиду?

Comment: @Zhekich, да, этот. Только непонятно, зачем вы его в мой ответ добавили вместо своего вопроса. По вопросу - если не видит студия в манифесте класс активити, то попробуйте прописать полное имя класса, вместе с пакетом. Т.е. `com.evgeniy.myapplication.MainActivity` вместо просто `.MainActivity`

Comment: Юрий, приложение запустилось. В приложении у меня есть кнопка которая добавляет в список, и когда на нее нажимаешь выходит ошибка, указанная выше

Comment: @Zhekich, это уже другой вопрос. Отметьте ответ как верный, если он помог, и задайте новый вопрос, в коем приведите код, укажите на какой его строке и с какой ошибкой и с каким логом падает.